# KineticJS: listening by .on()

Tags: jquery, bind, kineticjs

With KineticJS, is it possible, to bind the function only once? Like with the jQuery equivalent...

eg. in jQuery

```
// bad
$('.wrap a').on('click', myHandler);
// good
$('.wrap').on('click', 'a', myHandler);
```

I would like to do this with KineticJS as well, as there's going to be a lot of objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Eric from KineticJS.  Currently, you can use container.get() to get an array of nodes similar to jQuery, like these:

```
layer.get('Rect'); // returns all rectangles inside of layer
layer.get('.foo'); // returns all nodes with name foo inside layer
stage.get('#bar'); // returns node with id 'bar'
```

but you cannot yet bind events to all of the nodes via the selector like this:

layer.get('Rect').on('click', ...);

I'll add this to my todo list, so it should probably be released within a couple weeks :)

Cheers!

Eric

Comment: update on this thread - you can now bind handlers to a collection of nodes, and also iterate through them like jQuery as of v4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if there's any way to add a listner to all objects of a certain type (if thats what your trying to do).

Although you could make a group and add listeners to the whole group.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9vsps/

Just notice that if you drag something in the group, everything in the group will be dragged.